# C++ : Double free or corruption (out)

Tags: c++, memory, segmentation-fault

I'm getting this error

```
*** Error in `./main': double free or corruption (out): 0x000000000095c8a0 ***
```

- `getPieces()` is defined as `vector<Piece*> Position::getPieces()`
- `getSymbol()` returns an `int`

What I want to acheive is to remove from the vector the `Piece` pointer that is the same as variable `Pointer* piece`.

```
int Position::removePiece(Piece* piece) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < getPieces().size(); i++) {
    if (getPieces()[i] == piece) {
      getPieces().erase(getPieces().begin() + i); // errors happens here
      std::cout << getPieces().size() << std::endl;
      return getSymbol();
    }
  }

  return -1;
}
```

Comment: What Compiler and OS version are you using?

Comment: @itsols Archlinux and g++

Comment: @KerrekSB No, OP uses an iterator only once here. The problem is, iterator of one vector is used to modify another (which predictably fails).

Comment: @Abstraction: OK, fair enough. You'll still end up skipping over elements, which probably results in undesired behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, `getPieces()` returns a **copy** of a vector. Each time you call `getPieces()`, it's a different copy. You try to remove element from one vector using iterator from another, no wonder something goes wrong. Anyway, you try to modify a copy which will be destroyed when you leave the function (or even earlier).

If `getPieces` is a method of `Position` returning copy of internal field (say, `m_vector`), use `m_vector` in `removePiece()` instead of `getPieces` calls.